# How to fix "You seem to not be depending on “@angular/core” and/or “rxjs”. in ionic

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am trying to run Ionic project in local .I am  running the ionic serve command in cmd .I am getting
below error.

[image]

I have tried to run npm link command .I am getting error .

[image]

What are the commands I need to run  before ionic serve?

Comment: You are using witch version of ionic, angular, node? some old version of ionic need old version of npm, and you seem to have the android folder, so are you already make:
npm install?
ionic cordova platform add android? -> attention with ionic cli and your ionic version

You are using some proxy entreprise? some of them doesn't give you le right to access some external dependencies

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure to run `npm install` inside your project folder before you start.
2. Run `ionic serve` once again

**If it fails -**

1. Delete your `node_modules` folder and the `package_lock.json` file.
2. Run `npm install`
3. Run `npm link`

Comment: When to run ionic cordova platform add android command?

Comment: @REVATHI You should only add it after the `ionic serve` command works fine. (Also, if my answer solved your problem it would be great if you marked it as accepted)